# TextRenderer.MeasureText Returning Incorrect Value when Back and Fore Color is used

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm trying to measure the length of a string by using TextRenderer.MeasureText.This works fine if there is no text back/fore Color.But when i add a text background and foreground color,this returns a value less than the length of the drawn Bitmap.

```
intWidth = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(TextBox1.Text, myfont).Width ;
intHeight = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(TextBox1.Text, myfont).Height;
objBmpImage = new Bitmap(intWidth, intHeight);
Graphics newg = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage)
TextRenderer.DrawText(newg , TextBox1.Text, myfont, point, forecolor, backcolor);
```

This is the method im using.What im i doing wrong?

Comment: `MeasureText` method is a pain and not always accurate, but is shouldn't be affected by fore or back color. In fact, in [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66(v=vs.110).aspx) it is using a fore color. BTW,in your code you are using `MeasureString`,not `MeasureText` ?

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks...I actually Mixed up TextRenderer.MeasureText and Graphics.MeasureString.On using TextRenderer.MeasureText everywhere.. the issue seems to be fixed.